# Foreign key not registered in db angular (Field is null after submiting)

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have an issue with a foreign key that is not registered in db.
I have a form, with few inputs and a select.

The select looks like this

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="site_id">
  <option [value]="null" selected disabled>Select a site</option>
  <option *ngFor="let site of sitesList" [value]="site.site_id">{{site.name}} </option>
</select>
```

When i click on submit, it fill the form and send it

```
Form value : 
{numberplate_id: null, site_id: '4e9e2710-0c06-45f1-909e-36299f1b4780', num_plate: '1-HBO-999', dop: '2022-07-20', active: true}
active: true
dop: "2022-07-20"
num_plate: "1-HBO-999"
numberplate_id: null
site_id: "4e9e2710-0c06-45f1-909e-36299f1b4780"
```

Everything is registered/created in the DB except the Foreignkey, the field is null

**Frontend (numberplate_create.components.ts)**

```
export class NumberplateCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  errorMsg: string = '';
  successMsg: string = '';
  getParamId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  sitesList: Site[] = [];
  formGroup!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSitesList();
    this.initForm();
  }

  private initForm(): void {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      'site_id': new FormControl(),
      'num_plate': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'dop': new FormControl(''),
      'active': new FormControl(true)
    });

  }

  create(): void {
    if (this.formGroup.valid) {
      const payload: NumberplateCreatePayload = this.formGroup.value;
      console.log(payload)
      this.apiService.createNumberplate(payload).subscribe((response: ApiResponse) => {
        if (response.result) {
          this.formGroup.reset();
          this.successMsg = response.code;
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.errorMsg = 'All fields are required';
    }
  }

  getSitesList() {
    this.apiService.getAllSite().subscribe((response: ApiResponse) => {
      this.sitesList = response.data;
      if (this.sitesList == null) {
        this.errorMsg = response.code;
      }
    })
  }

}
```

**Frontend (api.service.ts)**

```
  createNumberplate(data: any): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/numberplate/create`, data)
      .pipe(
        map(response => response as ApiResponse)
      );
  }
```

**Backend (NumberplateCreatePayload.java)**

```
public class NumberplateCreatePayload {
    private String num_plate;
    private Date dop;
    private Boolean active;
    private Site site;
}
```

**Backend (Numberplate.java)**

```
public class Numberplate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID numberplate_id;
    private String num_plate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dop;
    private Boolean active;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "site_id")
    private Site site;
}
```

Any clues ?
Thanks

Comment: Nobody to help or give me a hint?

Comment: Can you also add your numberplateFormCreate code. let's see if FormControls are correct

Comment: @EricAska Hi Eric, i updated my Frontend (numberplate_create.components.ts), it include the formGroup previously named (numberplateFormCreate)!

Comment: i think you need to send `site` instead of `site_id` in your FormGroup since inside NumberplateCreatePayload you defined `site`. or you can change NumberplateCreatePayload to have `siteId` if you know the Backend and have access.

Comment: @EricAska i already made that changes but it does not solve the issue. Backend can't be touched

Comment: Nobody for a solution ? :(